# How to set object array value in Java from other method?

Tags: java, arrays, object, methods, input

I've already set up a class called Foodlist which include setters and getters.
My problem is, the value didn't set in each of the Flist[i] Array.

I was expecting different output for each Flist[i].getName when printing. But instead, the getName grab the last value from setName.

This is my code:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    Foodlist [] Flist = new Foodlist [3];

    for (int i = 0 ; i <Flist.length; i++)
    {
        Flist[i] = new Foodlist();
    }

    ReturnModel(Flist);

    for (int i = 0; i <Flist.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Model is "+ Flist[i].getName());
    }

}

static void ReturnModel (Foodlist[] Flist)
{

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    for (int i = 0; i < Flist.length; i ++)
    {
        String temp;
        System.out.println("Enter Food Name Please:");
        temp = input.next();
        Flist[i].setName(temp);

    }
}
```

Code of my foodlist.

```
    public class Foodlist
{
   static String Name;
   static int Price;
   static String Desc;

   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
       String nem;
       int pris;
       String des;

       nem = "";
       pris = 0;
       des ="";

       setName(nem);
       setPrice (pris);
       setDesc (des);


    }

    public static void setName (String nem)
    {
        Name = nem;
    }

    public static String getName()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public static void setPrice (int  pris)
    {
        Price = pris;
    }

    public static int getPrice ()
    {
        return Price;
    }

    public static void setDesc (String des)
    {
        Desc = des;
    }

    public static String getDesc()
    {
        return Desc;
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely your `name` field is `static`.

Comment: Can you show your implementation of `Foodlist`? It's hard to give you a good answer without seeing all of the relevant code. But my first guess would be that you're storing the name statically, so that all instances of `Foodlist` are getting the same name.

Comment: ReturnModel should be rename returnModel. Capitalize is only for Class, Enum, Interface.

Comment: @Gavin Added Foodlist code in the question :)

Comment: @RohitJain Is correct. After posting your full code it is obvious that your name variable is `static`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is due to the fact that you're storing the name statically, meaning that every instance of `Foodlist` is accessing the same name.

Furthermore, your getter and setter are static, so no matter which instance you have, it's calling a static getter and setter. You want to remove static from everything in your `Foodlist` class.

I see that you also have a `main` method in your `Foodlist` class, but you don't want this. I'm assuming you added this so that you can set default values for the fields in a new `Foodlist` instance. You'll instead want to replace that with a default constructor, which will start with `public Foodlist()`.